# CSS3 image rotate: image simply not rotating

Tags: html, css, image-rotation

I have an image within a div with the following CSS:

```
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
}

#container img:hover{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
```

But the image simply is not moving at all. I have checked in Chromes console and there are no CSS errors.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You know that you are doing 360 deg rotation? It is comming back to start position... Try rotate(180deg) etc instead...

Comment: Where do you expect it to rotate to? It's going full circle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Ugc5g/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are rotating 360 degrees, nothing is happening (because 360 degrees is a full circle). What you probably are trying to achieve is to animate this rotation so that it is visible. For this you need to set a transition in your css:

```
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

#container img:hover{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
}
```

Comment: Ugh! thanks - I wrongly assumed there was a defualt transition for this

Comment: No Problem. That's why we're here :D